# Suprised that f'{enum}' != str(enum) for Enums that have a str mixin, What's going on?

Tags: python, enums, formatting

Below, why is `str.__str__` (appearing to) take priority over the "more specific" `Mixin.__str__` and `Enum.__str__` for a `Mixin.BEE`?

Even though [Python docs on f-strings](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language) says:

> A general convention is that an empty format specification produces the same result as if you had called `str()` on the value. A non-empty format specification typically modifies the result.

What's happening under the hood?

```py
def format_vs_str(val):
    formatted, stred = f'{val}', str(val)
    if formatted != stred:
        raise ValueError(f'{repr(formatted)} != {repr(stred)}')
    return True


format_vs_str(1)  # True

format_vs_str('adsfa')  # True

Normal = Enum('Normal', {'BEE': 'BEE', 'C': 'CAT'})
format_vs_str(Normal.BEE) #  True

Mixin = Enum('Mixin', {'BEE': 'BEE', 'C': 'CAT'}, type=str)
format_vs_str(Mixin.BEE)  # ValueError: 'BEE' != 'Mixin.BEE'

Mixin.__str__(Mixin.BEE)  # 'Mixin.BEE'
Enum.__str__(Mixin.BEE)  # 'Mixin.BEE'
str.__str__(Mixin.BEE)  # 'BEE'
```

More Weirdness:

```py
class Foo(str):
    def __str__(self):
        return 'my own str'

foo = Foo()

str(foo)  # 'my own str'
f'{foo}'  # 'my own str'
str.__str__(foo)  # '' ???
```

Comment: You are looking at the documentation for the `string.format()` function.  The rules for f'' strings are slightly different.  The documentation there says it uses the `__format__` protocol.  I do not know why Enum's implement __format__ the way they do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`__format__` is being used instead of `__str__`. In code:

```py
enum = Mixin.BEE

[f'{enum}', str(enum)]                 # ['BEE', 'Mixin.BEE']

# underneath, will call dunders:
[enum.__format__(''), enum.__str__()]  # ['BEE', 'Mixin.BEE']

# "proof", see: https://docs.python.org/3/library/dis.html#opcode-FORMAT_VALUE
import dis
dis.dis("f'{Mixin.BEE}'")
#  1           0 LOAD_NAME                0 (Mixin)
#              2 LOAD_ATTR                1 (BEE)
#              4 FORMAT_VALUE             0
#              6 RETURN_VALUE
```

Comment: And presumably there's a default `object.__format__` method that falls back on `__str__`.

Comment: In Python 3.11 `format` and `str` will return the same thing.